# What does this ink level indicator mean

Tags: printer, gnome, ink

I am using a Canon MX922 printer through CUPS on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18. When I open the Printers dialog under Settings, I see an ink level indicator. There is 3 sections of the bar: Magenta, Black, and transparent. All of the ink tanks are almost full.

What do the different sections mean?

[image: Printers dialog]

**UPDATE (April 17, 2016)**

Now it looks like this: 
[image: Printers dialog]

**UPDATE (May 2, 2016)**

Now it looks like this: 
[image: Printers dialog]

All of these screenshots are from the same printer with the same set of ink.

Comment: Maybe purple is for color ink and black is for b&w ink.

Comment: @Paraney But I have more color ink left than black!

Comment: It's okay, at least you are two thirds full. I bet it will change again a few days later.

Comment: @Paraney The top one is from half a month ago with the same cartriges

Comment: It's possible that it means CUPS isn't properly interpreting the ink data.  I don't know about Canon, specifically, but for some brands, the ink level information only works (or works properly), with the proprietary driver, sometimes only in Windows.

Comment: @fixer1234 Maybe

Comment: The answer can probably be found [here](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center/tree/panels/printers/cc-printers-panel.c?h=gnome-3-20&id=8ca7aca07d7e9794439b4000a5a937e4f1b49877). I'll look into this